# How do Crimson/Demon Altars crafting work?

Tags: terraria

Everyone keeps saying Crimson/Demon Altars in Terraria are a craft station, and you just stand next to them.

I've tried all possible but I can only craft suspicious looking eyes from them. Multiple worlds didn't allow me to use them, and I have all the resources but all to no use.

Any idea to why this may be?

Answer (score 5):

Altars are special crafting stations and don't allow you to craft everything that can normally be crafted at a work bench. As the wiki mentions:

> They are used to craft pre-Hardmode boss-summoning items and the Night's Edge as well as the Void Bag and Vault.

(and also Ancient Hallowed armor pieces, which isn't in the wiki summary but is in the table)

You can see a full list of craftable items on [the wiki](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Altars#Used_to_craft) if you're fine with learning the recipes outside the game.